# Why is the Gb/s usually matched with the GHz for SDI?

Tags: frequency, serial, video, bandwidth, deserialiser

My knowledge in electronics and RF(because high speed data) is very surface level but attempting my best.

I'm attempting to do an application which utilizes 3G SDI, but am not understanding why there is an association the data rate with the frequency for the cable and connector interface. (e.g. 3Gb/s == 3GHz coax cable)

On one hand, I know digital signals have high frequency (theoretically infinite frequency). I also understand that the transmit side typically has some pre-emphasis, and on the receiving side there is a cable equalizer and a serial reclocker. Is the assumption that the high frequency attenuation is fine (given some distance) because the components on the receiving side is able to restore it?

Feel like I have a big knowledge gap and google can only go so far. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Looking at a FPGA development board which has SDI support (which haven't tested) it uses a [GV8601](https://www.semtech.com/products/broadcast-video/cable-equalizers/gv8601) to equalize and restore signals received over 75Ω coaxial cable, where the output from the GV8601 is connected to a Kintex-7 GTX transceiver. The datasheet contains ``The input signal passes through a variable gain equalizing stage, whose frequency response closely matches the inverse of the cable loss characteristic.``. There is also some information about the supported cable lengths (varies according to data rate).

Comment: You might get a better answer if you gave an example where 3 Gbps interface is said to associate with 3 GHz cable. Also for SDI, as it sends one bit per clock, the 3 Gbps does equate to 3 GHz bit clock on the interface, even if the 10-bit symbols are sent at 300 MHz clock.

Answer (score 2):

There's two primary reasons: first, all else being equal, as the data rate goes up the bandwidth of the channel goes up; second, because whatever decisions [SMPTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE) made in defining the standard, they ended up with a sorta-kinda 1:1 relationship between data rate and bandwidth.

This gets *really complicated*, with big tradeoffs between equipment cost and channel efficiency.  The foundational theory behind this is Nyquist's Channel Capacity Theorem, which you can look up -- but that's just a theorem that gives you an ultimate possible speed; it's only a very vague guideline for what's practical in achieving any particular speed when you're the one inventing the channel.

> I know digital signals have high frequency (theoretically infinite frequency).

A sharp-edged digital signal has theoretically infinite frequency content, but that's a very misleading factoid.  In practice, if you ignore delays, you can round off the edges of a digital transition to an arbitrary degree.  Also in practice, if you want to send consecutive pulses at a rate \$R\$, then the *minimum* bandwidth that you need to keep them from interfering with each other is \$B = R\$.

Then there's all sorts of complications associated with packing more than one bit into each pulse -- this is where Nyquist's channel capacity theorem gets complicated, as does using it.

> I also understand that the transmit side typically has some pre-emphasis, and on the receiving side there is a cable equalizer and a serial reclocker. Is the assumption that the high frequency attenuation is fine (given some distance) because the components on the receiving side is able to restore it?

*Up to a certain point*, yes.  But if it didn't matter at all, there wouldn't be requirements on the cable bandwidth.  Basically, the more you have to adjust for the cable's losses with preemphasis the more of your power budget you use for the "bad" frequencies.  The more you have to adjust for the cable's losses in the receiver equalization, the more you enhance noise at those frequencies.

So there are limits to how much you can adjust things.

Answer (score 1):

The same relationship holds true for other systems too. If the maximum data rate is 3 Gb/s then it's equivalent to a square wave of 1.5 GHz so, using a transmission medium that has a bandwidth of 3 GHz means that it's generally sufficient for transmitting the data without overly affecting the raw signal and its ability to be decoded. Call it a rule of thumb if you want.